# Automatically add text over image

Tags: image, photoshop, adobe-illustrator, sketchapp

Have to add different text over an image. The texts are in the table. There are about 10,000. How can I automate this process? Maybe script for Photoshop? Or something else?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What format is the table? What OS do you have available? Do you have to add all 10,000 texts to the same image - I hope it's big. Where do you have to place them on the image? What font? What colour? What size?

Comment: @MarkSetchell 
>What format is the table? 
CSV

>What OS do you have available?
macOS

>Do you have to add all 10,000 texts to the same image - I hope it's big. Where do you have to place them on the image?
Each text (row in the table) - on a separate image. The output will turn out 10,000 similar images.

>What font? What colour? What size?
At different patterns different fonts.

Comment: It is possible to read in a CSV in Photoshop and then add text from it to an image. But you'll need to "fill in the gaps" as Nick Datsky suggests. Also Stack Overflow isn't a script writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indesign, data merge works on both text and image.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktcbTtC3-Xk

There is a variable function in photoshop check this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IzpItHTvyo

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **ImageMagick**. It is most simply installed on macOS with **homebrew**, just:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Then if your table looks like this in `table.csv`

```
base1.png,180,100,result1.png,I have a dream
base2.png,20,90,result2.png,Four score and seven years ago
base3.png,50,180,result3.png,Gonna build me a wall
```

You would do the following in `bash` in the Terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read base x y result text; do
   echo DEBUG: $base $x $y $result $text
   convert "$base" -pointsize 18 -annotate +${x}+${y} "$text" "$result"
done < table.csv
```

And you would get this:

[image]
[image]
[image]